# ng-click not firing in nested directives

Tags: angularjs, django, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to build nested directives for a quiz application where the outer directive corresponds to a question, and each inner directive to a possible answer.  When the user clicks an answer, it disables itself and the other options, changes its color, and sends a POST request back to the server.

Or at least that's the end goal.  For the time being, I'm trying to just have the choice buttons call a 'click' function and log out a simple message.  To my frustration, I can't get ng-click to do anything.

Here's a hugely pared down version of my code that reproduces the issue:

```
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function (){

angular.module('exercise', [])
.directive('question', QuestionDirective)
.directive('choice', ChoiceDirective);

function QuestionDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true,
        controller: function($attrs, $scope) {
            $scope.question_id = $attrs['id'];
        },
    }
}

function ChoiceDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: true,
        require: '^question',
        link: function(controllerInstance, element, scope, attrs) {
            //this is firing!
            console.log(controllerInstance.question_id);
            scope.click = function(){
                console.log('click')
            }
        }
    }
}})();

</script>

<div ng-app='exercise'>
    <div question id="1" status="2">

         <p>
            1: Question?
         </p>

        <button choice
                ng-click="click()">choice 1</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

A couple notes: 
I'm using django for my back end and I'm embedding some data into DOM attributes when the page is retrieved so I don't want to put the html in a template.
I'm also using django templating to create a bunch of these questions and choices, and in my less-pared-down version of the code the choices are successfully logging their respective questions' ids.

I tried:

```
ng-click="click()"
ng-click="scope.click()"
ng-click="$scope.click()"
```

each to no success.

I want to use a link function rather than a controller because I want to use the parent directive's controller to get access to the parent question's id (and be able to disable the question when any of its choices are answered).

edit:
Also worth noting, I tried adding:

```
ng-disable="disabled"
```

to the choice directive and toggling a disabled variable in the link function and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong arguments sort should be `link: function(scope, element, attrs)`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/v59L0hnf/1/)

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('choice', ChoiceDirective);

function ChoiceDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //this is firing!
            scope.click = function(){
                console.log('click')
            }
        }
    };
};
```

If yo need also a controller it should be the last argument `link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller)`

Comment: I can accept an answer in 1 minute.  Was planning on it!